# Increase or Decrease the Pitch of the audio file using C#

Tags: c#, audio, xna, soundeffect, pitch-shifting

I want to increase and decrease pitch of an audio file (.m4a, mp4, etc).

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5

I have tried out the following link from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940201.aspx), but no success yet

Here in the above link, even after importing the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio`, its not recognizing the `SoundEffectInstance` and `SoundEffect` class.

So is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to use XNA only to alter audio? Seems like overkill. Anyway, you need to install XNA Game Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/245646/How-to-change-the-pitch-and-tempo-of-a-sound

Take note at the bottom... ***19th September, 2011: Added C# wrapper for cpct_dll.dll and a GUI demo for CPCT.**